# Debug rest in PhpStorm

Tags: rest, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

A new functional in new PhpStorm 11 is debug rest api within build-in rest api tool. I setup debugger and all works from browser - application stops on breakpoints.
[image]

But when i run debug from rest api tool, my breakpoints be ignored.
[image]

What i missed? On jetbrains blog said:
"To use the debugger, just make sure Xdebug is configured and enabled. Now you can use the new “Submit request in debug mode” button to easily send the request and initiate the debugger."

Comment: 1) What xdebug log says about it? 2) On your screenshots I see that you are using different servers (host and IP differs) -- have you created "PHP | Servers" entry for `127.0.0.1:8081` ? In other words -- please make sure that you can debug the same URL via browser. If you can then you should be able to do that via REST client as well.

Comment: @LazyOne, second screenshot is not mine - it's just to show debug button. I can debug url via browser, but can't via rest client.

Comment: #1 still applies. BTW -- do you have "phone handle" icon active at that point or not? Does PhpStorm shows debug console at all or not? Maybe consider recording short screencast which would show all details.

Comment: @LazyOne sorry, i don't have any xdebug logs. I tried with "phone handle" active and inactive. Here you can see screencast https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18200906/rest%20debug.mp4

Comment: Well -- 1) You need to collect [xdebug log](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) in order to see what is going on 2) the debug session seems to be created but then nothing seems to happen (BTW -- try closing them) 3) Maybe, due to some logic, you have more than 1 request in a queue (e.g. some activity done internally via sub-request) -- in such case try increasing max simultaneous debug sessions in PhpStorm. Cannot really suggest anything else based on the info you have provided so far -- it could be something simple and obvious but we are missing it.

Comment: @f0rtis have you ever found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger and xdebug session from PHPStorm’s REST client 
you can set the debug cookie manually. Add the following to a new Request header:

```
Name: Cookie
Value: XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you.

Try to change Xdebug port. I changed it to 9001 and it works.

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 128
```

Storm

[image]